# PHP friendly url .htaccess - search page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess file works fine with the following url

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/product/category/Girls-Clothes
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /product/category/category.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^product/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ /product/category/category.php?cid=$1
```

**but when i use page number along with friendly url, it would not work**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/product/category/Girls-Clothes?pno=2
```

i have tow variables **cid** and **pno**, CID is mentioned in .htaccess but when i wtore "pno" its gives me sql error.

```
RewriteRule ^uk/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /uk/category/category.php?cid=$1?pno=$1
RewriteRule ^uk/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ /uk/category/category.php?cid=$1?pno=$1
```

please let me know where i am doing wrong

Comment: You ought to be using an ampersand (`&`) between the querystring parameters. Like: `/uk/category/category.php?cid=$1&pno=$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current attempt, you are replacing the value of `pno` with the same value in `cid`, "Girls-Clothes", and I suspect that isn't what you want.

Just use the `QSA` flag to append the existing query string onto the request, so the `pno=` is passed through the rewrite along with the `cid` parameter you added.

```
RewriteRule ^uk/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /uk/category/category.php?cid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Notice also I reduced it to one line by appending `/?` and removing `/` from the `[]` to make the trailing slash optional.

Comment: is my anchor link is corrent...(http://www.mywebsite.com/product/category/Girls-Clothes&pno=1)...but it gives me error object not found..

Comment: @ReelMark The query string should start with `?pno=` not `&pno=`. The way you have it, the `&` would cause it not to match your rewrite rule pattern and you'd get a 404.